# Get FedEx oAuth token from "Authorization API"

Tags: asp.net-core, httprequest

I can get the Fedex "access_token" when I create a Post request from Postman. I add the "client_id" and "client_secret" to request body as Raw string as given in the Documentation ([Fedex](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/authorization/v1/docs.html)).

PostMan creates C# Code as follows :

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token");
request.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.Headers.Add("Cookie",.......some cookie....");
var content = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=...clientid...&client_secret=....client secret.....", null, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

When I use this code in Visual Studio for testing, on `request.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` I get the error message :

```
Misused header name, 'content-type'. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.'
```

After searching answers I revert my code to this :

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token");
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "...clientid..."),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "..client secret....."),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","client_pc_credentials")});
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "UTF-8";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token"), content);
        
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I call this method like `var oAuth = MakeApiCallAsync();` This code runs without errors, but it doesn't hit the last code line (`return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`) and the flow continues to the calling method and the variable oAuth  gets value of (Result = Yet not computed,  ..... other properties)

I tried nearly all the methods and I am exhausted, any ideas what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the response code of your request, something like below. This will let you know if your request is going through successfully or getting any errors.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token");
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "...clientid..."),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "..client secret....."),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","client_pc_credentials")});
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "UTF-8";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token"), content);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
 else{
    //api request error handling code   
}
```